# My program goes through the loop an unexpected amounts

Tags: java, loops, panel

As the header clarifies, a loop of mine that should only go through it 1 time (after toying with it, this made it the most obvious) goes through it twice, sometimes thrice.

It is weird, I cut out everything that confused me (still very new to java), but it doesn't change anything.
So now I know that it has to do with the panel somehow, but I can not for the life of me figure out, what might be the issue. I even removed all getter and setters. Somehow that loop runs through 2-3 times. 
(originally I had it draw dots but after it showed some weird behaviour I tried to figure it out, since the code is just taken from an online tutorial) Even tried break; but no to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
public class drawDot extends JPanel {

    //GetterSetter gs = new GetterSetter();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //super.paintComponent(g);

        //Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        //g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        // Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 0;i++) {
            // int y = 50;
            //g2d.fillOval(gs.getX(), y, 30, 30);
            // gs.setX(gs.getX()+30);
            System.out.println("30");
            break; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawDot points = new drawDot();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Points");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(points);
        frame.setSize(250, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop for something that needs to be executed only once?

Comment: Your loop runs once every time that Swing calls the `paintComponent()` method. Swing calls `paintComponent()` whenever it thinks it has to repaint your component, which could be hundreds of times if your program runs for longer periods of time.

Comment: Thank you! So paint component is the problem.
Thx ^^ 

Also: it "only" loops once because I tried to simplyfy the problem down to its roots, which includes reducing the loop down to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your JPanel is repainted it will call the paintComponent. It can be repainted many times during the execution of your program.

You can create a static variable `paintCounter` in your class and then print it out in the loop along with the loop index to see how many times your loop is run during single invocation of the paintComponent.

```
private static paintCounter = 0;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    paintCounter = paintCounter + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("30");
        System.out.println("PaintComponent called " + paintCounter + " times, loop index " + i);
    }
}
```